# Variable disappear from panel C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to import a panel and set it visible when a function is "run / executed". My problem is I have a static class and need to set some control's `visible = false` and when I import

```
var th_boosty = new Boosty();
```

this, the panel disappears.

```
static Panel panel = new Panel();

public Boosty()
{
    Controls.Add(panel);
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static void Add()
{
    var th_boosty = new Boosty(); // This disappear my panel

    panel.Visible = true;
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80,80,80);

    th_boosty.panel2.BringToFront();
    th_boosty.panel4.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: I assume you call the `Add` method more than once? A control can have only one parent. When you call `Add` a second time, a new `Boosty` is created and a panel is added to it, while this panel is removed from the previous `Boosty`.

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag.

Comment: I execute it only 1 time.

Comment: @HHopter Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I have a minimal reproducible example can be compiled by everyone only by adding this source code and adapt it for your code. At least tell what is my error in the question i can fix in the futur.

Comment: The above code does not make much sense. In the few provided lines, **there are many unusual things** and the code is not a minimal reproductible example because we cannot guess how it is used. Amoung weird things are **(1)** static `panel` variable for a control. **(2)**, manually adding a panel before `InitializeComponent` (why not drop a panel from the designer?). **(3)** static method `Add` to create itself out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one panel instance for each instance of the `Boosty` form, i.e., `panel` cannot be static.

```cs
public partial class Boosty : Form
{
    private Panel panel = new Panel {
        Visible = true,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 80, 80)
    };

    public Boosty()
    {
        Controls.Add(panel);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void Add()
    {
        var th_boosty = new Boosty(); // This disappear my panel
        th_boosty.panel2.BringToFront();
        th_boosty.panel4.BringToFront();
        th_boosty.Show();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boosty.Add(); // Added this for a test.
    }
}
```

Since you cannot access an instance field from a static method, I configured the panel with an object initializer.

The form will not be visible until you call `th_boosty.Show();`.

I am not sure what you are trying to achive. If `panel` has `DockStyle.Fill` any other control not being docked will remain hidden. Calling `BringToFront()` on `panel2` and `panel4` will probably not help. You might have to create a [`UserControl`](https://www.dotnetstuffs.com/create-user-control-csharp-winforms/) having the other panels on it instead of using a simple `Panel`.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your (deleted) comment, because this is not what your actual code is doing. Are you trying to create a [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)?

Comment: Doing some modifications, i'm sorry my code was blocking at some points. Thanks for helping